# Can't get the element value of an xml file with python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I am working on a program which has to parse some values. The xml is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<annotation>
   <folder>leaf_Haritaki</folder>
   <filename>Haritaki_010001.png</filename>
   <segmented>0</segmented>
   <size>
      <width>1456</width>
      <height>2592</height>
      <depth>3</depth>
   </size>
   <object>
      <name>Haritaki</name>
      <pose>Unspecified</pose>
      <truncated>0</truncated>
      <difficult>0</difficult>
      <bndbox>
         <xmin>316</xmin>
         <ymin>301</ymin>
         <xmax>1179</xmax>
         <ymax>1964</ymax>
      </bndbox>
   </object>
</annotation>
```

I need to parse the values of `<xmin>` `<ymin>` `<xmax>` `<ymax>`

I have tried this code. But I didn't find any value.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('Haritaki_010001.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for country in root.findall('bndbox'):
    name = float(country.find('xmin').text)
    print(name)
```

It provides a blank output. Would anyone please get a solution for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [ElementTree documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

> `Element.findall()` finds only elements with a tag which are direct children of the current element.

You are searching for a nested element, so `findall()` can't find that from the root. That is, unless you use an [*XPath expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support).

The expression `.//bndbox` would find the element anywhere in the tree. You probably want to find and handle the child elements, you could take the name from them after finding *all*. `.//bbndbox/*` would find all child elements:

```
>>> root.findall('.//bndbox')
[<Element 'bndbox' at 0x10c1775e8>]
>>> root.findall('.//bndbox/*')
[<Element 'xmin' at 0x10c177638>, <Element 'ymin' at 0x10c177688>, <Element 'xmax' at 0x10c1776d8>, <Element 'ymax' at 0x10c177728>]
```

Use that to create a dictionary (with a dictionary comprehension); you can even convert the contained text to integers at this point:

```
box = {e.tag: int(e.text) for e in root.findall('.//bndbox/*')}
```

Demo:

```
>>> box = {e.tag: int(e.text) for e in root.findall('.//bndbox/*')}
>>> box
{'xmin': 316, 'ymin': 301, 'xmax': 1179, 'ymax': 1964}
>>> box['xmin']
316
```